# Format Date from String in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a string that has a date in it and I wan't to be able to convert it.

```
var startDate = "March-09-2010"; 
var convertedStartDate = new Date(startDate); 
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1 
var day = convertedStartDate.getDay(); 
var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear(); 
var shortStartDate = month + "-" + day + "-" + year; 
alert(shortStartDate);
```

I want it so it converts **March-09-2010** to **09-03-10**  (DD-MM-YY)

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dt=Date.parse(Yourstring);

formatDate('DD-MM-YY',dt);
```

Please check this [Date.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4w173wk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'Parse'...thats the error

Comment: @RajatSinghal Sorry Edited the answer.

Comment: 1. *Object 1268089200000 has no method 'tostring'*. 2. after fix: *toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36*.

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = "March-09-2010"; 
var convertedStartDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/")); // replace hyphen with slash
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1 
var date = convertedStartDate.getDate(); 
var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear(); 
var shortStartDate = date + "-" + month + "-" + year; 
alert(shortStartDate);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BjnBW/

Comment: it doesn't work. "March/09/2010" is still not a valid date string. "March, 9 2010" is a valid date string.

Answer (score 0):

your date string is not in the correct format. for correct formats, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

try this or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AE4MS/2/)

```
var startDate = "March-09-2010";
var tmp = startDate.split('-');
tmp.splice(1, 0, ',');
var convertedStartDate = new Date(tmp.join(' '));
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1
var day = convertedStartDate.getDate();
var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
var shortStartDate = ('0' + day).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + month).slice(-2) + "-" + year;
alert(shortStartDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax changed your code a little, modify it according to it then ---

```
var startDate = "March/09/2010";
var convertedStartDate = new Date(startDate);
var month = convertedStartDate.getMonth() + 1
var day = convertedStartDate.getDate();
var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
var shortStartDate = day+ "-" + month+ "-" + year;
alert(shortStartDate);
```

Comment: Problem is in the startDate not matching the criteria

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDateFromFormat()` to convert string to date in javascript.

Check this link for more help: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/

Answer (score 0):

```
var shortStartDate = 
  Globalize.format(Globalize.parseDate(startDate, 'MMMM-dd-yyyy'), 'dd-MM-yy');
```

Use some library to do the conversion, because the built-in Date.parse() is implementation-dependent. It depends on the system locale what formats it accepts.

The code above uses Globalize.js, which can handle a large number of date formats, including formats with month names in different languages (the default being English).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert 'March' to a number. One way is to use this Array extension to be able to retrieve a month number from a month name:

```
Array.prototype.enum = function(){
     var obj = {};
     for (var i=0; i<this.length; (i+=1)) {
        obj[this[i]] = i;
     }
     this.enum = obj;
     return this;
};
```

Now, create an Array with month names

```
var months = ('January,February,March,April,May,June,July,'+
             'August,September,October,November,December').split(',')
              .enum();
```

Now you rewrite your date:

```
var startDate = "March-09-2010".split(/\-/),
    month     = months.enum[startDate[0]]+1;
startDate     = [startDate[1],
                 month < 10 ? '0'+month : month,
                 startDate[2]].join('-');
//=> startDate now is: '09-03-2010'
```